# What exactly is a/the BaseAccount in Solana?

Tags: rust, blockchain, account, solana

Solana noob trying to learn how to develop here :)

I am reading through the documentation and working on a couple programs and keep seeing mentioning of a `BaseAccount` or Base Account in both programs and documentation, that being said, I don't see any clear definition of a base account in the developer documentation https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts

What exactly is a Base Account? Does every program have a Base Account? Or is it a global variable kind like the SystemProgram?

Comment: where did you see term "BaseAccount "?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I read it on this blog here https://imfeld.dev/writing/starting_with_solana_part02 among a few other places

Comment: This seems specific to the tutorial that you're reading.  They're using `BaseAccount` as the name of the type used by their program, so nothing special in the name! The docs you linked in your question give the info you need.